# WatchKit detect tap / touch on label / group

Tags: ios, objective-c, watchkit, wkinterfacelabel

I have a nested `WKInterfaceGroup` with a `WKInterfaceLabel` within as such:

[image]

which looks like that:

[image]

> the orange highlight indicates which part of the value the user is currently editing. (Backgroundcolor of WKInterfaceGroup)

i am trying to find a way to switch between left/right highlighted and am running into the problem

- WatchKit does not provide me with something along the lines of `touchesBegan`
- WKInterfaceLabels have no action selectors
- WKInterfaceGroups have no action selectors
- There is no publich ForceTouch API

my question is:

> how can i let the user `tap' to select which of the two groups he wants to actively edit?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a WKInterfaceButton instead. Buttons allow you to use a group for their contents instead of a label. Then, hook into the action method of the button.